# Creating a shell environment for git hooks and Git Tower

Tags: linux, git, shell, git-tower

I'm using Git Tower. My project has some git hooks that aren't running. According go the Git Tower FAQ:

> You need to make sure you're creating the required shell environment
>   in the hook script itself (like modifying "PATH"), not in your shell
>   profile, as the hook script is called from the Tower process
>   environment which is not running in a shell environment (hence your
>   shell profile is not loaded).

This is quite foreign to me. My shell script is quite simply:

```
#!/bin/sh
git ftp push
```

What do I need to do in order to get Tower "permission" to process my hooks?

Comment: is this question still pending? If so I can help you with this. Please let me know.